# Send push-notification every time website is updated

Tags: ios, push-notification, web-scraping

I want to make an application that sends out a push-notification every time a website is updated with new content. This website is updated 1-3 times every day. And it's contains a chronological feed, where each post had a datetime, video/image, title.

And I want the notification to contain this information, and link to the website(maybe via the app).

Now what method should I use to get this app going? How should I start, and proceed?

Comment: You can use push notification as a flag (0-1, true-false) that indicate app to call web service, and that web service will delivered fresh-new content to the application.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? I will accept answers that just helps.

Comment: @Kampai would you care to elaborate? It would help me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

From your question's description, What I understood is this that you need to update your application whenever your website has new content.

This can be easily achieve using Remote/Push notification.

You can use `Boolean` type or `String` type which can be understand by app and web.

For example:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Hello World",
        "sound": "default"
        "Content": {
                 "isNewContent": "1",          
        }  
    }
}
```

This is typical Custom notification object, you can send more details in that.

Here you see that in `Content` there is a parameter `isNewCotent` which has a value `1`, this indicates that you have new content on web.

So now you can get call webservice to get new content from web server.

And If you dont know that how to implement Push Notification in iOS, you can check below tutorial, explained in detail.

[Setting Up Push Notifications on iOS](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925)

Comment: Okay. Now the website (http://skam.p3.no/) is not mine. And it adds new posts few times a day. How do I know when it gets updated, do I need to do a background check every minute from the app to see if there is new content? And also, how do I extract the content from the website and add it to the push-notification.

Comment: This website is for a norwegian TV-show. Extremely popular. And I want to make an app that send a notification every time there is a new post.

Comment: You need a web service call from that web site to know that there is a new content, contact that website developer.

Comment: There has to be a way without contacting and working with the website developers

Comment: Never did this before but you can try to collect some links from Web-Page source, but it is too difficult and there is less possibilities that we can get source URL.

Comment: Maybe using Google App Engine + Firebase Cloud Messaging would work?

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging is also deliver Push Notification as like Apple does, lets say in more fancy way, But the thing here is that how you'll get notification. I mean in Fire base also you need to send Notifications there is no automatic way.